# Required inputs (['flattened_patches']) are missing from input feed (['input_ids', 'attention_mask']) while executing ORTModel.generate()

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, onnx

Essentially i have an error when doing inference on Colab for my locally exported decoder-encoder ONNX pix2struc-doc-vqa model, here is the code showing the creation of the ONNX for inference using the Optimum Package

```
from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM
from transformers import Pix2StructConfig
onnx_model = ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM(
                                  encoder_session = ort.InferenceSession("/content/drive/MyDrive/vqa_model5/encoder_model.onnx"),
                                  decoder_session = ort.InferenceSession("/content/drive/MyDrive/vqa_model5/decoder_model.onnx"),
                                  config = Pix2StructConfig.from_pretrained("/content/drive/MyDrive/vqa_model5"),
                                  onnx_paths = "/content/drive/MyDrive/vqa_model5",
                                  use_cache = False,
                                  )
```

The below indicates the inputs that have been passed to the above ORT Model

```
ORT_inputs = {
    'encoder_attention_mask': torch.from_numpy(ORT_inputs['encoder_attention_mask']),
    'input_ids' : torch.from_numpy(ORT_inputs['input_ids']),
    'decoder_attention_mask' :torch.from_numpy(ORT_inputs['decoder_attention_mask']),
    'encoder_hidden_states' :torch.from_numpy(ORT_inputs['encoder_hidden_states']),
    "flattened_patches" : torch.from_numpy(inputs.flattened_patches[0])
}
```

```
The outputs are as follows

'encoder_attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0]]),
 'input_ids': tensor([[  361,   296, 30762,   311,     1]]),
 'decoder_attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]),
 'encoder_hidden_states': tensor([[[-0.1657, -0.0821, -0.6837,  ..., -0.5882, -0.1754, -0.1801],
          [-0.2243,  0.6748, -0.5702,  ..., -0.3200, -0.1716, -0.2030],
          [ 0.0133,  0.7141, -0.4358,  ..., -0.3122, -0.1749, -0.1788],
          ...,
          [ 0.3903,  0.4602,  0.3584,  ...,  1.1325, -0.3174, -1.0485],
          [ 0.3903,  0.4602,  0.3584,  ...,  1.1325, -0.3174, -1.0485],
          [ 0.3903,  0.4602,  0.3584,  ...,  1.1325, -0.3174, -1.0485]]]),
 'flattened_patches': tensor([[1.0000, 1.0000, 0.3988,  ..., 0.3988, 0.3988, 0.3988],
         [1.0000, 2.0000, 0.3988,  ..., 0.3988, 0.3988, 0.3988],
         [1.0000, 3.0000, 0.3988,  ..., 0.3988, 0.3988, 0.3988],
         ...,
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])}
```

The main code where i use the model.generate(), when passing the ORTinputs, i have been getting the following errors

```
onnx_model.generate(**ORT_inputs)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-82-b4c824cd3fb0> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 ORTModel.can_generate(onnx_model)
----> 2 onnx_model.generate(**ORT_inputs2)

6 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py in _validate_input(self, feed_input_names)
    193                 missing_input_names.append(input.name)
    194         if missing_input_names:
--> 195             raise ValueError(
    196                 f"Required inputs ({missing_input_names}) are missing from input feed ({feed_input_names})."
    197             )

ValueError: Required inputs (['flattened_patches']) are missing from input feed (['input_ids', 'attention_mask']).
```

but clearly, i have passed all the corresponding values from the ORTinputs to the generate() but the code is throwing me errors, that flattened_patches have been missing and the main goal of the code is to run inference and i cannot move forward without fixing it as i have not found any errors like it in the internet. I want to know what is wrong with it, and what is the explanation behind the error.